# Entity framwework does not find the database

Tags: entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

I have a .Net Core 6 console application that connect to a local SQL Server, this works fine on my dev computer. But when I try the same application on the server where the database is installed it doesnt work, I get an error telling me it cannot find the database. What could be wrong?

Comment: Is your connection string using integrated security or a SQL account? How is the console application being launched? Just running manually /w a logged in session, or via something like a Tasck Scheduler task? Lots of possible variables to consider. If you install SQL Management Studio on the DB machine you are running on you should be able to connect using the same connection string as the application is using. This can help shed light on possible authentication and authorization related issues.

Answer (score 0):

Update, I had to add the following to my connection string to get it to work.

;Trust Server Certificate=true